# While resuming upload, getting the size of data that had been uploaded always failed (500 internal server error)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

When resumable upload had been failed, I tried to get to the size of data that had been successfully uploaded as guided in
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resuming_a_failed_chunk
But server always return 500 Internal server error.

By the same reason, com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute() always failed (upload failed for some reason(socket timeout..) -> retry -> get size of data successfully uploaded -> 500 error )

[Log]

```
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): -------------- REQUEST  --------------
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Upe55Y_KlG2---SKIP----vSIWg
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): Accept-Encoding: gzip
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHE---SKIP---Qo9GN
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): Content-Range: bytes */2148165
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.10.3-beta (gzip)
07-06 10:20:14.320: I/GDTest(29334): Content-Length: 0
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): -------------- RESPONSE --------------
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): 500 Internal Server Error
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Content-Length: 180
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Content-Type: application/json
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 10:20:14 GMT
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Pragma: no-cache
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 14 2012 02:12:09 (1339665129)
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): X-Android-Received-Millis: 1341570014983
07-06 10:20:14.980: I/GDTest(29334): X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1341570014772
07-06 10:20:14.995: I/GDTest(29334): -------------- REQUEST  --------------
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that this is caused by a bug as the request looks correct (and usually a 500 response is caused by bug).

Does this happens always with the same file? If yes, could you share that file with me?
Have you tried something similar with a different (smaller) file?

Comment: It was fixed automatically.(server returns 308) 
Thanks.